# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=\frac{1}{y^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Solve the equation,
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=\frac{1}{y^3}$$
We have $$y^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y^4=1$$
I tried using change of dependent variable

Let $z=y^3\frac{dy}{dx}$
Then we get
$$y^3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+3y^2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{dz}{dx}$$
But i could not get an equation completely involving $z,x$

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\left\{-\frac{1}{2} e^{-i \left(c_2+x\right)} \sqrt{2 c_1 e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+e^{4 i c_2+4
   i x}+c_1^2-4},\frac{1}{2} e^{-i \left(c_2+x\right)} \sqrt{2 c_1 e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+e^{4
   i c_2+4 i x}+c_1^2-4},-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{c_1^2 e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+e^{-2 i c_2-2 i x}-4
   e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+2 c_1},\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{c_1^2 e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+e^{-2 i c_2-2 i
   x}-4 e^{2 i c_2+2 i x}+2 c_1}\right\}$$

Comment: Typically when the independent variable is missing from your differential equation you want perform the substitution $w=y'$. Since $y''=w\frac{dw}{dy}$ your equation becomes $wdw=\bigg(\frac{1}{y^3}-y\bigg)dy$ which is seprapable.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
y'' + y = \frac{1}{y^{3}} & \Longleftrightarrow y''y' + yy' = \frac{y'}{y^{3}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y')^{2} + y^{2} = -\frac{1}{y^{2}} + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y')^{2} = \frac{cy^{2} - y^{4} - 1}{y^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \pm\sqrt{\frac{cy^{2} - y^{4} - 1}{y^{2}}} 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Another Way to look at it

$$\frac{d^2y}{d^2x} = \frac{1}{y^3} - y  =>  \frac{d^2y}{d^2x} = \frac{1-y^4}{y^3}   =>$$
$$\frac{y^3}{1-y^4} d^2y = d^2x $$

Now this can be double integrated using the integral of a division formula

Answer (score 0):

*Another possibility*

Switch variables to make
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}+y=\frac 1 {y^3}$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives a separable equation
$$-\frac {p'}{p^3}=\frac 1 {y^3}-y\implies p=\pm\frac{y}{\sqrt{c_1  y^2-y^4-1}}$$ Now
$$x+c_2=\pm \int \frac{y}{\sqrt{c_1  y^2-y^4-1}}\,dy=\pm \frac 12 \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{c_1  t-t^2-1}}$$ and you will arrive to some arctangent.